Ajv validator test in Jest
I am trying to test my Ajv schema validator using Jest. Let my schema be userSchema, I then have:
const UserSchema = ajv.compile(userSchema)

In the application this works fine, if it is passed an invalid schema then UserSchema will throw a ValidationError. This is as expected since I have some validation keywords which are async in userSchema. Now, I want to create a test that checks that valid and invalid data are validated appropriately. I expect to have the data available if the validation succeeds, so to test valid data I use:
test('check valid data', async () => {
  expect(await UserSchema(user)).toBeTruthy();
}) 

and this works. However, for testing invalid data I keep running into issues. I am using:
test('check invalid data', async () => {
  expect(async () => {await UserSchema(user);}).toThrow(ValidationError);
})

but this does not work. When I run the test, it gives Received function did not throw and Test suite failed to run as two separate errors. The second is a result of validation failed which comes from running await UserSchema(user) - coincidentally this is the message given when a ValidationError is thrown and also can be seen when testing manually.
I don't understand why this test does not run as it should. The compiled schema definitely throws a ValidationError I have tested this manually in my API by including a console.log(error instanceof ValidationError) as the first statement in the catch block after calling UserSchema. As expected, when testing manually and passing invalid data this logs true.

If it's a promise, it .resolves or .rejects: https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-async

@jonrsharpe Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This question is definitely a duplicate of the other as well. Thank you again.
